# issue comparing dates on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I am trying to compare two dates which works properly on every device except the iPhone.Its giving wrong alert on iPhone.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euL2j5cn/11/)

```js
function play_time() {
    var crntTime;
    var today = new Date();
    var formattedTime = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    var crntDatetime = `${today} ${formattedTime}`;
    crntTime = new Date(crntDatetime).getTime();

    var check = '2020-08-18 23:14:07';

    var gameTime = new Date(check).getTime();

    if (crntTime <= gameTime) {
        alert('Play');
    } else {
        alert('Later');
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="play_time();"> show Time </button>
```

Comment: The Date constructor varies from platform to platform. You're passing in a format that the iOS code does not recognize.

Comment: @Pointy Which format should i use?

Comment: See Mr Crowder's answer. Anything other than the ISO standard is risky. Another alternative is to use a library like Moment that allows you to explicitly tell it what your date format means.

Comment: Also your formatted time is not actually formatted. You need to pad that too in my opinion. Much better to use a proper date: `const now = new Date().getTime(); const check = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd,hh,min,ss,0).getTime();  if (now <= check) ...`

Comment: @mplungjan Its still returning NAN for this `var check = '2020-08-18 23:14:07';`    `var gameTime = new Date(check).getTime();`

Comment: So create the date the way I suggest

Comment: @mplungjan How can i do that?

Comment: @mplungjan It is giving wrong result `-1321942553000` with that date `gameTime`.

Comment: Sorry. I was on my phone `const [d,t] = check.split(" "), [yyyy,mm,dd]=d.split("-"), [hh,min,ss]=t.split(":"), gameTime=new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd,hh,min,ss,0).getTime();`

Comment: And choose a date in the near future too

Comment: @mplungjan Its working now, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a space between the date and time in your `check` example, you're straying outside of the specification. That means that the implementation can use local time, or UTC, or refuse to parse it entirely.

Use [the date time format in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) which is basically what you have but with a `T` instead of space, or use the multi-argument `Date` constructor (for local time), or `Date.UTC` (passing the result into the `Date` constructor) for UTC. If parsing a string ideally always specify `Z` for UTC or a timezone offset. Date-only forms (`"2020-08-19"`) are parsed in UTC but date-time forms (`"2020-08-19T00:00:00"`) are parsed in local time — **but**, that changed more than once during the years 2015-2017 so it's a bit risky to rely on it.

In your situation, since you already have the information as separate variables, I would definitely use the multi-argument version of `new Date` or `Date.UTC`+`new Date` (depending on whether you want local or UTC).